# Is it beneficial anymore to unroll loops in C++ over fixed-sized arrays?

Tags: c++, optimization, stdarray, loop-unrolling

I want to use the `std::array` to store the data of N-dimensional vectors and implement arithmetic operations for such vectors. I figured, since the `std::array` now has a `constexpr` `size()` member function, I can use this to unroll the loops that I need for the arithmetic operations over its elements.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <array> 
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<std::size_t N=0, typename Vector>
void plus_equals(Vector& result, Vector const& input) 
{
    result[N] += input[N]; 

    if constexpr (N + 1 < result.size()) 
        plus_equals<N+1>(result, input); 
}

template<typename INT, size_t N>
class Vector
{
    std::array<INT, N> data_; 

    public: 

        template<typename ... BracketList> 
        Vector(BracketList ... blist)
        :
            data_{std::forward<BracketList>(blist)...}
        {} 

        INT& operator[](std::size_t i)
        {
            return data_[i]; 
        }

        INT operator[](std::size_t i) const 
        {
            return data_[i]; 
        }

        decltype(auto) begin() const 
        {
            return data_.begin(); 
        }

        decltype(auto) end() const 
        {
            return data_.end(); 
        }

        decltype(auto) end() 
        {
            return data_.end(); 
        }

        constexpr decltype(auto) size()
        {
            return data_.size(); 
        }

        void operator+=(Vector const& other)
        {
            plus_equals(*this, other); 
        }
};

template<size_t N = 0, typename Vector> 
Vector operator+(Vector const& uVec, Vector const& vVec)
{
    Vector result {uVec};  

    result += vVec;  

    return result;  
}

template<size_t N = 0, typename Vector> 
Vector sum(Vector const& uVec, Vector const& vVec)
{
    Vector result {uVec};  

    for (decltype(result.size()) i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
        result[i] += vVec[i]; 

    return result;  
}

template<typename Vector> 
void print(Vector&& v)
{
    for (const auto& el : v) std::cout << el << " ";  
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    Vector<int, 3> c1 = {1,2,3}; 
    Vector<int, 3> c2 = {3,2,1}; 
    auto r1 = c1 + c2;
    print (r1);

    auto r2 = sum(c2, c2);
    print (r2); 

    Vector<int, 3> s1, s2; 

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        cin >> s1[i];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        cin >> s2[i];

    auto r3 = s1 + s2;
    print(r3);

    auto r4 = sum(s1, s2);
    print(r4);


    return 0;
}
```

The `sum` operation is implemented using `plus_equals` that should unroll the individual `+=` operations on elements of the Vector, and the `sum(Vector const&, Vector const&)` function, uses a `for` loop.

I compiled the example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PQp9xz) using `-O3 -std=c++2a`.

If I comment out everything apart from

```
Vector<int, 3> c1 = {2,11,7}; 
Vector<int, 3> c2 = {9,22,5}; 
auto r1 = c1 + c2;
print (r1);
```

I get

```
    movabs  rax, 141733920779
    sub     rsp, 24
    lea     rdi, [rsp+4]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+4], rax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 12
    call    void print<Vector<int, 3ul>&>(Vector<int, 3ul>&)
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

What is happening here? Why can't I see the first two constants `c1[0] + c2[0]` and `c1[1] + c2[1]`? On the other hand `7 + 5 = 12` is moved:

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 12
```

Why is the assembly of the code

```
int main()
{
    Vector<int, 3> c1 = {2,11,7}; 
    Vector<int, 3> c2 = {9,22,5}; 
    //auto r1 = c1 + c2;
    //print (r1);

    auto r2 = sum(c1, c2);
    print (r2);
```

exactly the same?

If I try to use runtime variables:

```
    Vector<int, 3> s1, s2; 
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        cin >> s1[i];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        cin >> s2[i];

    auto r3 = s1 + s2;
    print(r3);
```

I get

```
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+28]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    lea     rdi, [rsp+36]
    add     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+20]
    add     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+16]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsp+24]
    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsp+12]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+44], eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+36], ecx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], edx
```

Which links to the `plus_equals` function template and unrolls the iterations as expected.

For the `sum`:

```
Vector<int, 3> s1, s2; 
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cin >> s1[i];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cin >> s2[i];

//auto r3 = s1 + s2;
//print(r3);

auto r4 = sum(s1, s2);
print(r4);
```

The assembly is:

```
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    add     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+20]
    add     ecx, eax
    shr     rax, 32
    add     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+28]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+44], edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+36], ecx
```

And there are no equality comparisons and jumps, so the loop has been unrolled.

When I look at the assembly code of the `sum` template, there are comparison operators and jumps there. This I expected because I figure that the compiler generates a general code first, for any `Vector`, and then later on figures out if `Vector::size()` is `constexpr` and applies further optimizations.

Is the interpretation OK? If so, can one conclude that there is no sense in manually unrolling iterations for fixed-sized arrays, because with `-O3` the loops that use `constexpr size` member functions will be unrolled anyway by the compiler?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you measure and profile that your previous code was to slow for your requirements, or that it was a bottleneck in your program? Did you check if the compiler didn't already do some unrolling or other optimizations? It's not a premature optimization?

Comment: I have profiled my code many times with hpctoolkit and scorep. This doesn't have anything to do with my question: if there is a guarantee that the compiler unrolls the loops when it has `constexpr size()` in the loop definition, it would make the code much more readable with for loops then with recursive funtion templates. This is important because the code is scientific and will possibly be extended by others.

Comment: Standard doesn't guarantee that any loop would be unrolled. In fact, a compiler might even re-roll a manually unrolled loop (not that I would know of a case where a compiler would do so - but such case might exist).

Comment: @eerorika: OK, thanks! So if this were your bottleneck, you would use templates instead of relying on the compiler?

Comment: " if there is a guarantee that the compiler " - you don't even have to continue, the answer is already 'no', so I guess that answers your question.  There are no guarantees about how the compiler does any optimization outside of the language specification.

Comment: @tmaric Sure. If I've found a bottleneck, I might check if this produces measurable improvement.

Comment: Q: Perhaps this is silly, but why doesn't plus_equals need to be marked constexpr? I did check that the assembly is no different if it is marked so, I had just assumed it would need to be marked constexpr in order to be unrolled.

Comment: If you want the gcc/clang to unroll the loop when the size is known at compile time (no matter `constexpr` or not), use flag `-funroll-loops
`. `--param max-unroll-times=...` can control unrolling depth. These days compiler doesn't do aggressive unrolling normally, because the CPU can handle loop pretty efficiently. But there are still some cases adding `-funroll-all-loop` will make significant improvement, due to the non-negligible throughput impact of `jcc`. Especially some subpar gcc vectorization, they have the same performance as unrolling a loop, which isn't done by default.

Comment: _Why can't I see the first two constants _  These are combined into the `movabs  rax, 141733920779` instruction (that decimal number is `210000000B` in hex).

Comment: Side-note: Performance-wise, you almost certainly want to accept the first argument to `operator+` and `sum` by value, not by `const` reference, and get rid of the `result` value internally (so the body would be just `uVec += vVec; return uVec;`). Accepting by value means you'll avoid a copy entirely when the operand is an r-value. See [Binary arithmetic operators on the operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/364696).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is intelligent enough to automatically unroll loops for you, and you should trust that it's going to be able to do those (and many other) optimizations.

Generally speaking, the compiler is better at making micro-optimizations, while the programmer is better at making macro-optimizations.

### Micro-optimizations (what the compiler CAN do):

- Unroll loops
- inline functions automatically
- apply tail call optimization to speed up tail-recursive functions (many end up being as fast as the equivalent loop)
- elide copies and moves: if you return something by value, in many cases the compiler can get rid of the copy or move entirely.
- Use vectorized floating point instructions (this one still requires you to help the compiler sometimes, though)
- Eliminate unnecessary or redundant if statements (for example, when you check something, and then cal a member function that also checks it, when it inlines the member function it'll eliminate the unnecessary check)
- Inline lambdas passed to other functions (it only does this if you don't wrap it in `std::function` - it can't inline `std::function`)
- Store local variables and even entire structs in the registers, instead of using RAM or Cache
- Lots o' math optimizations

### Macro-optimizations (what the compiler CAN'T do):

These are the things the programmer still has to pay attention to.

- Change the way data is stored. If something doesn't need to be a pointer, store it on the stack!
- Change the algorithm used to calculate something. Algorithm design is still important!
- Other stuff